# oracle trigger before deleting not working

Tags: oracle

I have the following trigger:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOL.AFTERIUDLIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE
   ON SOL.LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD + 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :NEW.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :NEW.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :NEW.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;

   IF DELETING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD - 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :NEW.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :NEW.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :NEW.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;
END;
```

The case `if` inserting working fine, but the case id deleting not. Any idea ?

Comment: What exactly does "*not working*" mean? Do you get an error when you compile the trigger? Do you get an error when the trigger fires? If yes which is the **exact** error message? Does it update the wrong rows? Does it update nothing? Does it update to much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're deleting, [the field values in the `NEW` pseudorecord are all null](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955), so nothing matches when you query using those fields. You need to refer to `OLD` instead:

```
   IF DELETING
   THEN
      UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS
         SET INLD = INLD - 1
       WHERE     CUSTOMERID = :OLD.CUSTOMERID
             AND ID = :OLD.APPOINTOFCAID
             AND KINDCONTROLID = :OLD.KINDCONTROLID;
   END IF;
```

You may have a concurrency issue if two sessions insert or delete simultaneously; the final value you get in `APPOINTSOFCAS` after they both commit might not be what you expect.